# Check multiple values in array

Tags: swift, struct

I have a struct:

```
struct Info {
    var name: String = ""
    var number = Int()
    var count = Int()
}

var infoProvided : [Info] = []
```

I want to check if name and number is already filled in, and if so, update the counter. If neither name nor number is filled in, I want to append the values.
Something like this:

```
//Check if item allready exists, if not append to array
if let index = infoProvided.index(where: { $0.name == name }) && infoProvided.index(where: { $0.number == number })   {
    infoProvided[index].count += counter

} else {
    infoProvided.append(Info(name: name, number: number, count: counter))
}
```

The above solution does not work:

> "Optional type 'Array.Index?' (aka 'Optional') cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!= nil' instead"

How can I check if the two values exists?

Comment: There's a lot of red flags here. All properties mutable (`var` instead of `let`), have nonsensical defaults (`""` is a valid name?)). What's `Info`? Practically the only things computers deal with is information. What kind of information is it, *specifically*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you want to update the `Info` instance with the matching name and number.

For that you need to check both in a single call to `index(where:)`.

```
if let index = infoProvided.index(where: { $0.name == name && $0.number == number }) {
    infoProvided[index].count += counter
} else {
    infoProvided.append(Info(name: name, number: number, count: counter))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeatedly looking up the same objects with `index(where:)` would be very inefficient (each call is a `O(n)` linear search). It would be better to use a Dictionary, which would also radically simplify your merging/addition logic:

```
struct Info { // TODO: NAME ME BETTER
    let name: String
    let number: Int  // TODO: NAME ME BETTER
}
```

... somewhere else in your code:

```
var infoCounts = [Info: Int]

func addNewInfo(name: String, number: Int, count: Int) {
    infoCounts[Info(name: name, number: number), default: 0] += count
}
```